# Compute inner poduct without IML

Tags: arrays, matrix, sas

I am trying to create a macro that compute the inner(dot) product of a vector and a matrix.

```
 Y*X*t(Y) ## equivalent to the Sum(yi*Xij*yj)
```

I don't have IML, so I try to do it using array manipulation.

1. How to create a multidimensional array from the data to avoid index
   translation within single array.
2. How to debug my loop, or at least print some variable to control my program?
3. How to delete temporary variables?

I am a SAS newbie, but this is what I have tried so far:

```
%macro dot_product(X = ,y=, value= );
 /* read number of rows */
 %let X_id=%sysfunc(open(&X));
 %let nrows=%sysfunc(attrn(&X_id,nobs));
 %let rc=%sysfunc(close(&X_id));
 data &X.;
 set &X.;
 array arr_X{*} _numeric_;
 set &y.;
 array arr_y{*} _numeric_;
 do i = 1 to &nrows;
    do j = 1 to &nrows;
        value + arr_y[i]*arr_X[j + &nrows*(i-1)]*arr_y[j];
    end;
 end;
 run;
%mend;
```

When I run this :

```
%dot_product(X=X,y=y,value=val);
```

I get this error :

```
ERROR: Array subscript out of range at line 314 column 158.
```

I am using this to generate data :

```
data X;
array myCols{*} col1-col5;
do i = 1 to 5;
    do j = 1 to dim(myCols);
    myCols{j}=ranuni(123);
    end;
    output;
end;
drop i j;
run;
/* create a vector y */ 
data y;
array myCols{*} col1-col5;
do j = 1 to dim(myCols);
  myCols{j}=ranuni(123);
end;
output;
drop j;
run;
```

Thanks in advance for your help or any idea to debug my data.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit:* The following relates to the description of the question, how to evaluate a quadratic form using dot, inner or scalar products. The actual code is nearly fine. *end edit*

If you want to reduce it to dot products, then your value is the dot product of the linearization of X_ij and the same linearization applied to Z_ij=Y_i*Y_j.

The other way is to portion X_ij into its rows or columns depending on the linearization of the matrix, and compute separate dot products of Y with, say, each row. Of the resulting vector you the compute the dot product again with Y.

---

*Edit added:* The length nrows of the nested loops in the code should be determined from the length of the vector y, perhaps with a check that the length of x is nrows*nrows.

Comment: Thanks. But I think my problem is not mathematical here. I Know how to compute the dot product by row/or by column . I want to compute `x*A*t(x)` using SAS.

Comment: Of course you can not just call the dot product on x and y. Your x has 25 components, y has 5. But you can splice x into 5 parts of 5, compute the dot product for each of them, form a new vector u of the values and then compute the dot product of u and y. Or you produce z as the dyadic product of y with itself and then call dot product on x and z.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you show me some SAS code please?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know the SAS vector commands and philosophy. I'm just telling you that your present code does not look like the required triple product and that the reported error is because of incompatible object sizes. If I knew more, I would have put it into an answer.

Comment: I should sleep, this is are the comments to my answer. Good night.

Comment: In your code above, a first fix would be to change the computation of nrows from using the length of x to using the length of y. So that nrows=5 and not 25. And please do not name it dot_product, this is usually reserved for the matrix product and had me confused. Sleep helps.